# WinRT Xaml Numeric Keyboard doesn't popup

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, inputscope

I have an universal app and in my app I am using

```
InputScope="Number"
```

for many of my textboxes. And in phone application all working, but in windows tablet app when I use it in emulator it opens numberic keyboard (however I am still able to navigate to alphabetical keyboard but this is not an issue).

Issue is with actual tablet. When I use my application in tablet it opens alphabetical keyboard then I have to navigate to numeric keyboard.

What I have tried so far

changed `InputScope` to Telephone.

Tried in code for changing input scope.

Comment: Please show the C# code that you tried for setting input scope.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `NumberFullWidth` ?

Please go to : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue for more types that you can use ..

**UPDATE :**

Have you tried another tablet !!

Comment: I am trying this but I don't know why it is working on emulator but not on actual tablet

Comment: just xaml, but I am using keydown event of textbox to handle characters other than digits. So that user can only input numbers in textbox

Comment: Wired .. I think that I can't help you any more Sorry!